# AmbiguousMatchException En asp.net mvc 5 c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Tengo problema al tratar de enviar un id por url, la cosa es que ese id se esta llamando desde una partialview() y me tendría que redirigir a otra vista, pero me genera la siguiente excepción AmbiguousMatchException.

Aqui la forma en que mando el id:

```
http://localhost:52509/TiposAsesores/delete_usuario_grup/18
```

En la vista del partialview(), el boton donde se envia el id es:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("delete_usuario_grup","TiposAsesores", new { id = item.GrupAsesor})" class="btn btn-danger" title="Eliminar del grupo"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
```

Y asi se ve desde el navegador:

```
<a href="/TiposAsesores/delete_usuario_grup/18" class="btn btn-danger" title="Eliminar del grupo"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
```

Y este es la accion del controlador que recibe el id:

```
public ActionResult delete_usuario_grup(int id)
    {
        Sto_TipoAsesor_Usuario_NE STAUNE = new Sto_TipoAsesor_Usuario_NE();
        Sto_TipoAsesor_Usuario STAU = new Sto_TipoAsesor_Usuario();
        STAU.Id_TipoAsesor_Usuario = id;
        STAU = STAUNE.ListarByID(STAU);
        return View(STAU);
    }
```

Y este es el error completo que me genera al cargar la vista:

```
La solicitud actual para la acción 'delete_usuario_grup' en el tipo de controlador 'TiposAsesoresController' es ambigua entre los métodos de acción siguientes: 
System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult delete_usuario_grup(Int32) en el tipo             SistemaDeSeguimientoEstudiantil.Controllers.TiposAsesoresController
System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult delete_usuario_grup(CapaEntidad.Sto_TipoAsesor_Usuario) en el tipo SistemaDeSeguimientoEstudiantil.Controllers.TiposAsesoresController
```

Alguien podría asesorarme sobre como solucionar este error

Comment: Tienes dos funciones llamadas delete_usuario_grup en el controlador TiposAsesoresController?

Answer (score 0):

Tienes repetido el action que invocas y crea ambiguedad, mira la documentacion de microsoft:

> An AmbiguousMatchException is thrown when a member is invoked late-bound and multiple overloads satisfy the binding criteria, or when more than one member matches the binding criteria passed to a reflection method that can return only a single result (for example, Type.GetMethod or Type.GetProperty).

Traducción

> Se genera una AmbiguousMatchException cuando un miembro se invoca con destino tardío y múltiples sobrecargas satisfacen los criterios de enlace, o cuando más de un miembro coincide con los criterios de enlace pasados ​​a un método de reflexión que puede devolver solo un resultado (por ejemplo, Type.GetMethod o Type.GetProperty).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.ambiguousmatchexception(v=vs.110).aspx